# Use Where and SelectMany

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following entities:

```
public class Position
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public Int32 PositionId { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all `Positions` which has a `Role` with `UserId = userId`.

I made it work using the following:

```
positions = positions
  .Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.UserId).Contains(userId));
```

How can I do this with `SelectMany`? Is it better?

Note that I need to return positions ... That was my problem when using `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need `Select` or `SelectMany`, simple where should work.

You need `using System.Linq` for this to work

```
  List<Position>  positions = positions
      .Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.UserId == userId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectMany` flattens a returned list of lists, but as you only return a list, there is no need for it (and you can't even use it).

It would come handy, if the `Role` class would contain a list of `UserId`s:

```
public List<Int32> UserId { get; set; }
```

Then the followind code would help you:

```
positions = positions
  .Where(x => x.Roles.SelectMany(y => y.UserId).Contains(userId));
```

Therefore a simple Select is better.

However, the best solution is the one that @Alen suggested, with Any.